How to use vue2/vue3 in sharepoint framework (vuespfx)
I tried to use vuejs in SharePoint framework according to the information found on the Internet, but it still failed. The version of the case framework I found was 1.8, and my current version was 1.19. Hope someone can give a latest version of the configuration process. Thank you very much.
Warning of gulp command
Project Dependencies
Build configuration Image
Class implementation
I added some plugins : vue-load, vue-template-compiler, as described in the configuration in the screenshot,
No error in the console, but you can't see what's in the Vue template in sharepoint.

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
